# KnpSnappyBundle PDF generation exceeds maximum execution time

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, twig

I'm trying to generate a PDF with [KnpSnappyBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle) in Symfony, but whenever I attempt to run the action to do so, it exceeds the maximum 60 second execution time in PHP.

Here is the action:

```
/**
* @Route("/download-agreement", name="download_agreement")
*/
public function downloadAgreementAction()
{
    $session = new Session();
    $html = $this->renderView('client-representation.html.twig', array(
        'clientAgreementData'  => $session->get("sessionClientAgreementData"),
        "pdfStatus" => true
        ));

    return new Response(
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="error.pdf"'
            )
        );
}
```

It also only seems to exceed the execution time when I use absolute urls for assets in the twig template, like `absolute_url(asset('css/agreement.css'))`. If I use relative urls, then the css will just get ignored and the PDF will generate, but of course I need the styling.

Any ideas?

EDIT: For anyone who has this problem, using absolute urls SHOULD work on a production server; on localhost however, you may get the problem I had. Thank you to [chalasr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34755410/3597216).

Comment: It sounds like it might be a problem with attempting to retrieve the absolute urls.  Try putting `set_time_limit(0);` as the first line in your controller action to remove the 60-second timeout, and then see if the page ever even finishes, or even try doing `return new Response($html);` to make sure you're still getting what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ok, the solution is really simple actually, the problem is that it wont work on dev(local) environment because for some reason the wkhtmltopdf doesn't like localhost:8000... whatever.

[From this issue](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/9) (and many other) opened for this problem in the laravel package.
Another on the bundle https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/issues/66

The first time I worked with KnpSnappyBundle, I used a lot of alternatives, unsuccessfully.

The 'timeout exceeded' occurs when trying to generate pdf using a view (same for all related methods of the `Pdf` class) which contains one or more absolute url(s).

To deal with this bug, I use a specific template used only for Pdf generation,  where I put the css directly in a `<style></style>` block.
Like this, the style is correctly applied.

Comment: Putting all of bootstrap in a style tag is definitely not ideal.

Comment: Use a CDN for bootstrap and other external libs. It's a quick and dirty alternative for a very blocking bug which occurs in a specific context  (only from localhost), also it will be really difficult for you to find an 'ideal' solution. Good luck